# select rows in a dataframe in python based on two criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Based on the dataframe (1) below, I wish to create a dataframe (2) where either y or z is equal to 2. Is there a way to do this conveniently?

And if I were to create a dataframe (3) that only contains rows from dataframe (1) but not dataframe (2), how should I approach it?

```
    id  x  y  z 
    0 324  1  2
    1 213  1  1
    2 529  2  1
    3 347  3  2
    4 109  2  2
```

...

Answer (score 2):

```
df[df[['y','z']].eq(2).any(1)]
Out[1205]: 
   id    x  y  z
0   0  324  1  2
2   2  529  2  1
3   3  347  3  2
4   4  109  2  2
```

Comment: Nice, this would generalise to multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks! This method makes a lot of sense, but I am getting an error saying "['y','z'] is not a label or index". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @csha did you try df[['y','z']]? or can you type list(df) and show you out put here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `df2` easily enough using a condition:

```
df2 = df1[df1.y.eq(2) | df1.z.eq(2)]

df2
      x  y  z
id           
0   324  1  2
2   529  2  1
3   347  3  2
4   109  2  2
```

Given `df2` and `df1`, you can perform a *set difference* operation on the index, like this:

```
df3 = df1.iloc[df1.index.difference(df2.index)]

df3 
      x  y  z
id           
1   213  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df2 = df[(df.y == 2) | (df.z == 2)]

print(df2)
```

Results:

```
   id    x  y  z
0   0  324  1  2
2   2  529  2  1
3   3  347  3  2
4   4  109  2  2
```

Comment: Please read the existing answers before you post your own, I've already covered this in my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47360167/4909087

Comment: i did not see your answer as I was writing mine. i can remove it though

Comment: It's not a problem if it was accidental. Just check before posting :-) It's fine if we post within 1-2 minutes of each other, but the difference between ours is almost 8 minutes.